# eclipse: why the gradle build errors are not attached with the sources?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

When I build the java project, it would give errors if any in the output console, but I could not click the error to jump the to source codes.

Is there any advanced option to enable this sensible requirement? Or, the eclipse does not support it?

Comment: What kind of errors? Compile errors or errors in the Gradle build script?

Comment: @howlger compiler errors, for example, syntax error in java source codes.

Comment: In the _Console_ or the _Gradle Executions_ view?

Comment: @howlger as I said, in the console.

Comment: Why would there be compile error when running Maven? Wouldn't all compile errors have been displayed and fixed by the developer already when editing the source files in Eclipse?

Comment: @Andreas sorry, I don't get your point. For example, when I compile a java file, the gradle build shows me 10 errors, then I could click each error which bring me to the corresponding source line so that I could check and fix the cause. That's IDE's expected feature, isn't it?

Comment: But where did you get that Java file from? The developer who wrote it, and who (of course!) ensured that the code compiles, before handing it off to you, right? --- And yes, a main feature of IDEs is to help locate compile errors, which is why they show them to you *immediately*, while you're still looking at the file in the IDE editor, *before* you ask Maven to build to final package. That is also what the `Problems` view in Eclipse is for: To see all errors in the project, so you can find errors in other source files caused by the change you just made in the current source file.

Comment: I don't think all errors could not be found only from the indications of IDE. And, if you create a normal java project and get compiler errors, the eclipse would generate the links to sources. But gradle in eclipse does not.

Comment: @Andreas I know your way, but could you confirm why gradle in eclipse does not provides error links to sources?

Comment: Probably because the developers didn't think it was needed, since the Eclipse project already would have found the errors when you developed the source code.

Comment: @kingluo If you report this feature to Eclipse, can you please tell the bug number? I'd like to vote for it, even it is only nice to have and not _sensible_ for me. (I guess, _this requirement_ instead of _this sensible requirement_ might have saved you some comments. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse Buildsiph does not yet support such a linking in the Console view. But you can [**request this feature here**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Buildship&bug_severity=enhancement&rep_platform=all&short_desc=Support%20linking%20in%20the%20Console%20view&comment=Feature%20request:%0AIn%20the%20console%20view.%20if%20there%20is%20a%20Java%20compile%20error,%20a%20click%20on%20the%20error%20should%20open%20the%20Java%20editor%20and%20go%20to%20the%20line%20with%20the%20error.%0A%0ASee%20also%20https://stackoverflow.com/q/48126063/6505250).

As a workaround you can:

1. Select filename with line information, e. g. `MyClass.java:42`
2. Copy the selection to the clipboard: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Alternatively, you can use [AnyEdit Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) which adds *Open File under Cursor* to the Console's right-click menu.